# Is there an online dictionary listing words spelled in reverse?

Tags: orthography

A final "s" in a word is usually pronounced \z\, so it is an interesting that the final "z" in "quartz" is pronounced \s\. (I mention interesting quirks like this to my ESL students.) I was wondering if there were any other instances like "quartz". If an on-line dictionary in ordered by the last letter of the word existed, this would be easy to check for, but the concept of a "reverse dictionary" seems to be limited to the (very useful) idea of going from definition/concept to headword. Searching for "dictionary in alphabetical order by the last letter" didn't seem to get me anywhere, but maybe I haven't searched diligently enough.

Comment: Just to clarify, you mean alphabetical ordering of the reverse of the word? (I.e., “quartz” would be with other words ending with Z.) I ask because “reverse alphabetical order” typically refers to the ordering you get by sorting according to the reverse of the alphabet (Z, Y, X, …).

Comment: Yes, I wanted the alphabetical ordering of the reverse spelling of the words. Sorry I wasn't crystal clear about that.

Comment: Good question +1. Suggestion: could you change your title to something like "Is there an online dictionary ordered by words spelled in reverse?"

Comment: It's known as a rhyming dictionary.

Comment: Try any of those **"anagram solvers"** in the Google Play Store

Comment: "A final "s" in a word is usually pronounced /z/". Not really, though...

Comment: @Amen: Could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Summary: Try [this word list](https://raw.github.com/shreevatsa/misc-math/bd2f1f564271105b08a44c6f75d49caec98370f6/wordlist-rev.txt) (2.4 MB) I just made.

---

I don't know of any such dictionaries, but it's easy enough with a little scripting to refashion any dictionary/word-list, available in an accessible electronic format, into what you want.

For instance, this script (in Python)

```
import sys
words = [w.strip() for w in sys.stdin.readlines()]
words = sorted(words, key = lambda w: ''.join(reversed(w)))
print '\n'.join(words)
```

run on the word list `/usr/share/dict/words` that ships with Unix systems gives [this word list](https://raw.github.com/shreevatsa/misc-math/bd2f1f564271105b08a44c6f75d49caec98370f6/wordlist-rev.txt) (2.4 MB). It takes a while to get the hang of looking up words in such a list, of course, because you have to read the words backwards. The string "quartz" occurs as part of words far apart, for instance:

```
…
propertyless
quartzless
mess
…
ritzy
quartzy
Shortzy
…
waltz
speltz
Fultz
Nantz
chintz
untz
wootz
quartz
biquartz
hertz
bortz
halutz
chalutz
```

I think what you actually wanted was just a word list rather than a dictionary, but it is also easy enough, equipped with a good free dictionary, to turn it into a dictionary in alphabetical order of the reversed words.

Comment: You are totally right, and your answer is totally cool. For example, I see that "waltz" is another such word. I will pass the link to your word list on to my students!

Comment: If you use a Linux computer, the _words_ file is 4.9 MB in size. It's at `/usr/share/dict/words`

Comment: You can do it on the command line: `rev /usr/share/dict/words | sort | rev > reverse-dict`. (I had to install a package to provides the words file; I chose `wamerican` which is ~1MB.)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to find other words like *quartz* that end in *-z*, *-tz* or *-rtz*, there are plenty of websites for Scrabble players and crossword solvers to find such words.

For example:

- http://www.scrabblefinder.com/ends-with/z/
- http://www.scrabblefinder.com/ends-with/tz/
- http://www.scrabblefinder.com/ends-with/rtz/
- http://www.findtheword.info/Search.aspx?stype=ends&sword=z
- http://www.findtheword.info/Search.aspx?stype=ends&sword=tz
- http://www.findtheword.info/Search.aspx?stype=ends&sword=rtz

This gives us words like *bortz, hertz, nertz, slivovitz, spritz, ritz, ansatz* and *kibbutz*.

Rather than bookmarking these sites, you can usually just [Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=ending%20with%20z) for something like *ending with z*.